# Multidimesional array into MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, forms

Desperately need help.

I have HTML form with six text fields and one select2 (JQuery). The select2 input can be multiple. There is also JS script which clones all the fields. So I need to process user input to MySQL as one row per one select2 selection. As far as I understand, it should be a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array [
  array[0] [
     key1 => value1
     key2 => value2
     ...
  ]
  array[1] [
     key1 => value1
     key2 => value2
     ...
  ]
```

The problem is that I can process either only one (last) array, or can't process anything at all.
Here's the used code:

cloneForm.js

```
$('#regData').on('click', '.regCloneAdd', function() {
    $('.js-select').select2("destroy");
    var $tr = $(this).closest('.regClone');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $('.js-select').select2();
    $clone.find('.js-select').select2('val', '');
});
```

The form itself is simple and put into table, so the .js clones table row

processForm.php

```
<?php

require("AuthSQL.php");

$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO `my_table` (`val1`, `val2`, `val3`, `val4`, 
`val5`, `val6`, `select2val`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssisii', $val1, $val2, $val3, $val4, $val5, $val6, $select2val);
        foreach ($_POST['select2val'] as $select2val) {
            $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
            $val2 = $_POST['val2'];
            $val3 = $_POST['val3'];
            $val4 = $_POST['val4'];
            $val5 = $_POST['val5'];
            $val6 = $_POST['val6'];
            $stmt->execute();
        }
?>
```

Is there a way to correctly insert into MySQL rows like:

```
val1(a), val2(a), val3(a), val4(a), val5(a), val6(a), select2val(a)
val1(a), val2(a), val3(a), val4(a), val5(a), val6(a), select2val(b)
val1(c), val2(c), val3(c), val4(c), val5(c), val6(c), select2val(c)
```

Comment: You may compact your data into JSON array of JSON arrays and send it to MySQL. Then the query will parse it to separate rows and values and store values into the table. But if your MySQL version is too old (approx. less than 8.0.4) then the query will be too complex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, my version is too old for this.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided the exact version.

Comment: You need a for loop instead a foreach and use the iterator to index your arrays in the post variables.

Comment: @Shadow, can you please elaborate on this? I'm quite new to php.

Comment: @Akina, version is 5.7.27

Comment: *version is 5.7.27* That's bad/ it is too old for laconic effective solution... Does some upper limit of the rows amount to be inserted exists? for example, not more than 1000 rows?

Comment: @Akina Not that I know of. It wouldn't be more than 100-120 rows upon submit in real usage though.